# How to load Observable array property as Angular Material Table data source?

Tags: angular, angular-material, observable

I have an Observable array property with the value fetched from Rest API.

Currently I am using ngFor to show the data in the standard html table.

Now I want to switch into Angular Material Table (MatTableDataSource). How do I load the [dataSource] with the data I have from the Observables?

Comment: Did my solution below help you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you go.  Hack away at this.  I have the observable in a service I call processor.service and it uses the same code is used to populate all my tables. The vars are in the component and are passed through to the service:

component

```
private dbTable = 'members';  // The table name where the data is.
private dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();

private displayedColumns = [
    'firstName',
    'lastName',
...]

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
 }

// ------ GET ALL -----

  private getAllRecords() {
    return this.mainProcessorService.getAllRecords(
      this.dbTable,
      this.dataSource,
      this.paginator,
      );
  }
```

processor.service

```
  getAllRecords(dbTable, dataSource, paginator) {

    dataSource.paginator = paginator;

    // Populate the Material2 DataTable.
    Observable.merge(paginator.page)
      .startWith(null)  // Delete this and no data is downloaded.
      .switchMap(() => {
        return this.httpService.getRecords(dbTable,
          paginator.pageIndex);
      })
      .map(data => data.resource)  // Get data objects in the Postgres resource JSON object through model.

      .subscribe(data => {
          this.dataLength = data.length;
          dataSource.data = data;
        },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.log(err.error);
          console.log(err.message);
          this.messagesService.openDialog('Error', 'Database not available.');
        }
      );
  }
```

My html isn't ngFor but should be useful.  The results create a long table that requires pagination and probably accomplishes what you want.

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
          <mat-header-cell fxFlex="10%" *matHeaderCellDef> First Name </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell fxFlex="10%" *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.first_name}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>


        <ng-container matColumnDef="lastName">
          <mat-header-cell fxFlex="10%" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Last Name </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell fxFlex="10%" *matCellDef="let row">  {{row.last_name}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
...
```

Answer (score 5):

Just `[dataSource]="Observable<ReadOnlyArray>"` works. The commit [feat(table): allow data input to be array, stream (#9489)](https://github.com/angular/cdk-builds/commit/4c4b21b5fea4731fc7e255c8ea4c40f0a49788aa#diff-8cd62b597e7b93b4884dc46bc259715a) seems at Angular 5.2 . For now, allowed types are [`DataSource<T> | Observable<ReadonlyArray<T> | T[]> | ReadonlyArray<T> | T[]`](https://github.com/angular/cdk-builds/blob/d20bd5270080172813577c58bab8ccf8fba06b50/table/typings/table.d.ts#L23).

Comment: Tried this in Angular 8 and it seems to work when binding to Observable<T[]>. Thanks.

Comment: @HadidAli - ts file declares an object of type `Observable<YourDataType[]>` and you bind to that object: `[dataSource]="yourObject"`.

Comment: This works as long as you don't need sorting, the sorting of column seems to need a `MatTableDataSource`

Comment: using this Observable approach, how would one implement a select/select all functionallity?

Comment: @Mackelito Well, this is just a quick way to display, not for full functionalities.

Answer (score -1):

You either need to create a custom `DataSource` or use the `MatTableDataSource`.

See [here](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview)